# WordPress ACF how to filter a textarea field content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, acfpro

I'm building a WordPress theme that uses the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) (ACF plugin). I have the following function via functions.php:

```
function filter_p_tags( $content ) {
    $content = str_replace( '<p>','<p class="custom__class">', $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_p_tags');
add_filter('acf_the_content','filter_p_tags');
```

The `<p>` tags via posts and pages are successfully being replaced with `<p class="custom__class">`. However, my ACF fields are not being filtered. What am I doing wrong here?

It's worth mentioning that the ACF fields in question belong to an options page. Here's how an option field looks within one of my templates.

```
<?php the_field( 'text', 'option' ); ?>
```

Comment: What's the type of your ACF field? Is it a `Wysiwyg`? Is it a `textarea`? Is it a `simple text` field?

Comment: I've just realised it's a textarea field. This explains why the filter isn't working. Facepalm!

Comment: Thanks @Ruvee. I've just tried your answer and it doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ACF field is a `textarea`, then you would want to use `acf/format_value/type=textarea` filter hook instead of using `acf_the_content` which would be applied on `wysiwyg`.

```php
add_filter('acf/format_value/type=textarea', 'filter_p_tags_acf', 10, 3);
```

So your entire code would be something like this:

```php
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_p_tags');

function filter_p_tags( $content ) {

    $content = str_replace( '<p>','<p class="custom__class">', $content );

    return $content;

}

add_filter('acf/format_value/type=textarea', 'filter_p_tags_acf', 10, 3);

function filter_p_tags_acf( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

    $value = str_replace( '<p>','<p class="custom__class">', $value );

    return $value;

}
```

---

##### Another way of doing this

Alternatively, as you suggested, we could use `acf/format_value/key={$key}` filter hook instead of using `acf/format_value/type=textarea`. Like so:

```php
add_filter('acf/format_value/key=field_abc123456', 'filter_p_tags_acf', 10, 3);

function filter_p_tags_acf( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

    $value = str_replace( '<p>','<p class="custom__class">', $value );

    return $value;

}
```

Comment: I was literally just about to offer up the same solution, but it still doesn't work. Weird because this is exactly what the ACF documentation suggests. Could this have anything to do with it being an options field? I've tried `<?php echo get_field( 'text', 'option' ); ?>` and `<?php the_field( 'text', 'option' ); ?>`.

Comment: Interestingly, I've just tried your snippet with `add_filter('acf/format_value/key=field_abc123456, 'filter_p_tags_acf', 10, 3);` and it works perfectly. For some reason, it's having trouble picking up on textarea fields.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out :)